# How do I listen to a Postgres stored procedure trigger from Go?

Tags: postgresql, go

In a Postgres database, I have a stored procedure that can be triggered as such:

`SELECT add_customer('name', 'lastname')`

I wish to listen to this trigger from my Go-code.

What I've tried:

```
    import (
        "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
        "github.com/lib/pq" 
    )

    // Code beforehand..

    db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", connStr)
    // Assume db is connected and works

    minReconn := 10 * time.Second
    maxReconn := time.Minute
    listener := pq.NewListener(psqlInfo, minReconn, maxReconn, reportProblem)
    err = listener.Listen("add_customer")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

In `main` of my code, I call a function that waits for notifications:

```
    go func() {
        somepackage.WaitForNotification()
    }()
```

That looks like:

```
func (k *someStruct) WaitForNotification() {
    select {
    // This case is never satisfied
    case notification := <-k.db.Listener.Notify:
        k.logger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("%v", notification))
        err := doWork()
        // ...
    }
}
```

As commented, the above code path is never reached.

Searching docs, it is evident that the stored procs are not the same as LISTEN/NOTIFY events in Postgres.

How do I listen to a stored procedure being triggered from Go?

Comment: Add a `NOTIFY` statement or `pg_notify()` call within your `add_customer` procedure so that you can listen to it in your Golang code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `add_customer` function to send a notification to the channel. To send the notification use the [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-notify.html) command or the [`pg_notify(text, text)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-notify.html#id-1.9.3.157.7.5) function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_customer(first_name text, last_name text) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT
    AS $_$
BEGIN
    NOTIFY add_customer, '<payload>';
    -- or
    SELECT pg_notify('add_customer', '<payload>');
    
    -- the rest of your code
END
$_$;
```

Comment: Would've liked to avoid that, but yes, this is the way more than likely. Thank you.